# Why define event handler member functions (inline) inside the constructor function in order to work with 'unbind'?

Tags: javascript, constructor, event-handling

While studying the source code for [a signature pad widget](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/blob/master/signature_pad.js), I find the following code snippet inside the constructor function (note in particular the **comment** in the following snippet):

```
var SignaturePad = function (canvas, options) {

    ...

    // MY QUESTION IS ABOUT THE FOLLOWING CODE COMMENT!!!
    // v v v

    // we need add these inline so they are available to unbind while still having
    // access to 'self' we could use _.bind but it's not worth adding a dependency

    this._handleMouseDown = function (event) {
        if (event.which === 1) {
            self._mouseButtonDown = true;
            self._strokeBegin(event);
        }
    };

    // ... other event handlers here

    ...

}
```

... for completeness in providing context for the above code, later the event handlers are bound as event listeners:

```
SignaturePad.prototype._handleMouseEvents = function () {
    ...
    this._canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this._handleMouseDown);
    ...
};
```

From the above code snippet, you can see the comment:

> we need add these inline so they are available to unbind while still having access to 'self'
>
> we could use _.bind but it's not worth adding a dependency`

I am scratching my head about this.  Why is access `self` required when unbinding (and I assume by 'unbinding' is meant detaching the event listener, but please correct me if I'm wrong)?

In other words, I'd like to understand the above code comment so that I can be certain I understand the JavaScript and/or event binding thoroughly in this code.

Comment: `self` itself isn't required to remove the event listener, but the original function is required, so they keep a reference to it.

Comment: @squint Thanks.  Couldn't the `_handleMouseDown` function be defined outside the constructor, and still be available to remove the event listener?

Comment: Not if different `_handleMouseDown` functions are created for different objects. Even if the function is structurally the same, a reference to the original is needed, so if each `SignaturePad` instances gets a separate handler created for it, then it needs to hold on to its own version.

Comment: ...looking at the linked code, that does seem to be the case. A separate handler is created inside the `SignaturePad` constructor, so each object gets its own unique function that must be used to unbind it.

Comment: @squint: Aah, that explains it.  If the code were to define the event handler in the prototype object, all instances of the signature pad would share the same handler (a bug).  Whereas by including the event handler definition inside the constructor results in each instance of the signature pad having its own instance of the event handling function.  You could write that as an answer, if you'd like.  Otherwise, I can.

Comment: I would add that now the author could use the standard bind() method with no need for dependency like underscore.js

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Almost. It isn't really a bug to share the event handler. However, they do want to be able to access the `SignaturePad` instance from within the handler, and that requires a separate closer to the `self` variable they created. They IMO would actually do better to make their objects implement the *EventListener* interface, and bind the object itself instead of a function. Then they get access to both the element and the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.addEventListener` calls in that code receive a function reference when binding the handler. In order to use `.removeEventListener` to unbind, you need to pass a reference to the *same* function handler.

Because the `SignaturePad` constructor creates a new, unique (though identical) function for each instance, and binds that function, they need to keep a reference to that function in order to unbind later on. Therefore they put it directly on the object for later use.

The reason they create these handlers inside the constructor function is that they want them to be able to reference the `SignaturePad` instance that was created. So they create a `var self = this` variable, and have the functions created in the constructor reference `self`. If the handlers were on the `.prototype`, there would be no way for that shared handler to reference the original object, given their approach.

---

Here's a truncated version of their code that shows how to use the *EventListener* interface:

```
var SignaturePad = function(canvas, options) {
  this._handleMouseEvents();
};

// Implements the EventListener interface
SignaturePad.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case "mousedown":
      this._handleMouseDown(event)
      break
    case "mousemove":
      this._handleMouseMove(event)
      break
    case "mouseup":
      this._handleMouseUp(event)
      break
    default:
      console.log("Unbound event type:", event.type)
  }
}

SignaturePad.prototype._handleMouseDown = function(event) {
  if (event.which === 1) {
    this._mouseButtonDown = true;
    this._strokeBegin(event);
  }
};

SignaturePad.prototype._handleMouseMove = function(event) {
  if (this._mouseButtonDown) {
    this._strokeUpdate(event);
  }
};

SignaturePad.prototype._handleMouseUp = function(event) {
  if (event.which === 1 && this._mouseButtonDown) {
    this._mouseButtonDown = false;
    this._strokeEnd(event);
  }
};

SignaturePad.prototype._strokeUpdate = function(event) {
  console.log("stroke update");
};

SignaturePad.prototype._strokeBegin = function(event) {
  console.log("stroke begin");
};

SignaturePad.prototype._strokeEnd = function(event) {
  console.log("stroke end");
};

SignaturePad.prototype._handleMouseEvents = function() {
  this._mouseButtonDown = false;

  this._canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this);
  this._canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", this);
};
```

So you can see that the `handleEvent` method was added, and we don't actually bind any functions using `.addEventListener`. Instead, we bind a reference to the `SignaturePad` object itself.

When an event occurs, the `handleEvent` method is invoked with the value of `this` pointing our `SignaturePad` object we bound. We still have access to the element as well via `event.currentTarget`.

So this lets us reuse functions on the `.prototype` and gives us all the object references we need. And of course unbinding is done the same way, except that we pass the object we bound to `.removeEventListener`.